# refreshing fragment inside viewpager with MVP architecture

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have a `fragment` called as detailFragment that hold a `viewpager` extending `FragmentPagerAdapter`, in that fragment i use a presenter to download the data before opening the viewpager.

> My Program is error, because the viewpager opening the childFragment
>   before the presenter in detailFragment is finishing retrieve the data.

Can i some guide me, prefent opening the `viewpager` before loading the data first, because the childFragment load data from the **DB**. I use android **MVP architecture**

What should i do in the detailFragment `onCreateView`? because there is where i initialize the ViewPager,

Thanks before,

Answer (score 0):

You should show a progressbar in your child fragment and once the data is available you can make it gone. You can use a callback from your detail fragment to child fragment to show the data and make the progress bar gone.